# Why do motors buzz when are applied PWM?

Tags: motor, pwm

Why do motors (DC) make a buzz sound when a low duty cycle PWM is applied to them?

Once I applied a 10% duty cycle PWM to a gear motor and it didn't move. just made a buzz sound. What does a low duty cycle do to a motor that makes it buzz?

Comment: Because they have the same elements as loudspeakers, but fortunately, less efficiently arranged for producing acoustic output.

Comment: Can you see the diaphragm of a loudspeaker moving at 1kHz?

Comment: @Andyaka you mean like this phenomenon? http://www.gifmania.com/Gif-Animados-Arte/Imagenes-Musica/Solfeo/Diapasones/Vibracion-Diapason-81483.gif

Comment: Have you seen all of the videos on YouTube of various music played on floppy drives? Same principle, just with stepper motors.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you drive a motor with a PWM signal, you are basically just turning it off and on very rapidly. If the motor is moving while this is happening, it's inertia (along with the winding inductance) smooth out the PWM signal such that the speed of the motor is proportional to the average time the motor is on.

If you use a very low duty cycle, it means that the motor is turned on for only a very small amount of time each cycle. If the average power supplied to the motor is too small to overcome the friction and any load on the motor shaft, the motor will stall. In the case of PWM it will be turned on, stall, then be turned off, over and over again, which essentially makes it vibrate at the PWM frequency. If this frequency is nicely within the audible range for humans (anywhere from ~20Hz to ~20kHz), you will hear this vibration as a buzzing sound.

The rotor vibrates in the magnetic field which is being turned on and off. You turn it on, it tries to rotate but can only move a small way before you turn the field off again, and which point it will stop moving again. It vibrates back and fourth. This may move any air around it, but also moves the whole motor - Newton's law: every action has an equal and opposite reaction! As the whole motor vibrates, the air around the motor will vibrate with it, making sound!

Try putting the motor on a hollow box, this will amplify the vibrations of the stator and the sound will get louder. Conversely, press it on to something like a piece of rubber and that will damp the vibrations - it gets quieter.

Comment: sound is produced when something hits some other thing. what is hitting another thing in this case?

Comment: Sound is produced when something is moving the air.

Comment: nothing is moving in the air here! the shaft is just rotating.

Comment: @BlueSky sound can be produced in more ways than just by something hitting something. The rotor vibrates in the magnetic field which is being turned on and off, which moves the air around it, but also moves the whole motor (every action has an equal and opposite reaction!). Try putting the motor on a hollow box, this will amplify the vibrations of the stator and the sound will get louder

Comment: @BlueSky sound is produced when something moves the air. A vibrating object moves the air and transmits its vibrating frequency. Like a speaker.

Comment: @BlueSky "nothing is moving in the air here! the shaft is just rotating." The shaft is surrounded by air, right? And rotation is a kind of movement?

Answer (score 3):

The current is going back and forth through the motor coils, generating alternating magnetic field, which in turn is generating mechanical micro-vibrations producing the sound.

Answer (score 3):

I've had this problem before. I solved it increasing the PWM frequency to an inaudible frequency (above 20 kHz). It is easy done in Arduino where you can set it up to 62 kHz. Google for "Arduino fast PWM". Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

There are several possible sources for buzzing.  As the magnetic field in the coils reverses the coil plates (motor coils are usually stacked plates to reduce hysteresis effects) are jerked and move slightly against each other. Motors built with more slop (imprecise machining) have the potential for the coils to rock slightly against the bearing rod as the magnetic forces reverse. The coil plate stack may expand and contract due to the compression applied and released as the field is applied and released.  Note that there are quiet motors, and these are usually machined and assembled to very tight tolerances so that there is much less opportunity for these vibration effects to take place.

Answer (score -1):

Most likely, the DC motor you are talking about is a geared motor. Gears have a backlash between the teeth to allow lubrication and prevent damage to the teeth. With low PWM, you are just supplying enough power to make the teeth move across their backlash and touch the mating tooth. This is the reason for the noise.